# e-banking from oversea bank to the UK bank & IBAN code

Tags: united-kingdom, international-transfer, online-banking, wire-transfer

I have paid my tuition fees with e-banking from my country to the UK.
And I've filled in SWIFT code and the addressee’s name, address, and  UK account number instead of IBAN code. 
This will be refused by the UK bank? 
I heard that banks in the Europe only accept IBAN code from other countries.
(My English is bad.. Please understand me..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done an International Transfer to UK via SWIFT, don't worry, UK still accepts the UK Bank Account number and it is not mandatory for IBAN to be used.